# objective-C syntax beginner question

Tags: iphone, objective-c

what is the syntax to use an object (NSString) that declared in another class?

object `workId` in class `works`, i want to use it's value in class `jobs`.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Go here:
http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

And scroll down to the "Properties" section.

Answer (score 1):

if you declared workId as a property and synthesized it, you should be able to access it using works.workId or [works workId]

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html

Comment: i need to declare it also in jobs class ?

Comment: You'll need to import the header for your works class into your jobs class' implementation, so jobs knows about works and what it can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to hold a pointer to the same object you can declare a second property in the Jobs class using 'assign' or 'retain', if you'd just like a copy you could declare the property using 'copy'.

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString* theString;
```

If Jobs has a pointer to Works like so:

```
@interface Jobs 
{
    Works* works;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) Works* works;
@end
```

You could just use self.works.workId to access the work id from within an instance of the Jobs class.

Could you let us know a little more about your particular use case, it would help to determine what you should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

in Person.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject {
    NSString * name;
}
@end
```

in Person.m:

```
@implementation Person

- (NSString*) name {
    return name;
}

- (void)setName:(NSString *)aName {
    [name autorelease];
    name = [aName copy];
}

@end
```